# the_taxonomies() doesn't accept custom separator

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type called cases. For this I have also created a custom taxonomy called "category". I have implemented the custom taxonomy as follows:

```php
function maestro_register_taxonomy()
{
    register_taxonomy(
        'case-category',
        'cases',
        array(
            'label' => __('Kategorie'),
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'cases/kategorie',
                'with_front' => false
            ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
        ),
    );

    //  Unregister post tag taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('post_tag', []);
}
add_action('init', 'maestro_register_taxonomy');
```

I would now like to output the taxonomies specified for each case with a custom separator using the_taxonomies() function:

```php
<?php if (get_the_taxonomies()) { ?>
    <span>
        the_taxonomies(array('template' => '% %l', 'sep' => '|', 'term_template' => '%2$s',));
    </span>
<?php } ?>
```

Now for my question:
Everything inside `the_taxonomies()` function works fine, but the separator just wouldn't change to `'|'` and still is `'und'` (german word for "and"). What do I do wrong?

Comment: According to the documentation, the default for `sep` would just be a simple space character. So if you are getting "und" instead, then there is probably some filtering going on, the theme or some plugin has probably hooked into this, and overwrites what you specified.

Comment: `'% %l'` looks wrong. Also, I’m not seeing any way to hook this either.

Comment: `the_taxonomies()` is printed in the html and not called in your code.